# Command output, pipe, script co-operation

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm writing a small script to restart my lighttpd server:
1. kill already running process
2. start new server

The script is the following:

```
PID=$(ps aux | grep lighttpd | grep -v grep | cut -c9-15) 
kill $PID
sudo lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

My problem is that in a terminal window the command

```
ps aux | grep lighttpd | grep -v grep | cut -c9-15
```

gives the result: **11685** but if it runs within the shell script than the result is **11685 13339 13340**

What am I missing here?

The ps output of the line containing the lighttpd job is
**root     11685  0.0  0.0  11096  1960 ?        S    16:40   0:00 lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf**

Comment: Does your script contain 'lighttpd' in its name or command-line parameters?

Comment: what does `ps aux | grep '[l]igthtpd'` show you, more than 1 process?

Comment: The script name is 'restart-lighttpd' THANK you so much for the solution!!! :)

Comment: You could also probably shorten this with `PID=$(pgrep -x lighttpd)`

Comment: Or better yet `pkill -f lighttpd`. If your O/S doesn't have `pkill` use `killall lighttpd`. If neither `pkill` nor `killall` exist, you can use `ps -o pid,comand | grep lighttpd | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'` or use `cut` instead of `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are wasting time in Linux/unix for grepping PID and killing it when you have killall command

`/usr/bin/killall`

You can directly

`killall lighttpd`  or `/usr/bin/killall lighttpd`

if not superuser then use sudo

`sudo killall lighttpd`  or `sudo /usr/bin/killall lighttpd`

can use preferably `-9` with `killall` like in your case would be `sudo killall lighttpd`

then restart it  via

`sudo lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

if you are looking for fully automated script then make use of `except` commands
[Click here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/)